# I get different results from keras.model.predict

Tags: keras

keras.model.predict gives different results for same inputs every time I run it.

I do not change anything, just run the cell which only has a line;

```
model.predict(x)
```

but results are varying every time.

why this happens?

Comment: This is impossible to answer given the current information, please add information of your model or even better, make self-contained reproducible example.

Comment: `x` is an iterator object?

Comment: no, x is an input data.